# Using sed to replace n characters before a keyword including the keyword?

Tags: sed

For replacing everything *before* a keyword piece of code below works well.

```
sed 's/.*keyword/string-to-be-replaced/'
```

But for replacing n characters before the keyword *including* the keyword I couldn't find a solution. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need *`n`* `.` dots.

```sh
n=[num]
sed "s/.\{$n\}keyword/REPLACE/"
```

...where *`[num]`* is meant to represent a positive integer should work.

Note that is different than *`.*keyword`* in at least a couple of important respects.

1. *`.*`* applies to any/all characters that occur before the *last* occurrence of *`keyword`* in `sed`'s pattern space, and so if there are multiple *`keywords`* matched at once, *`.*`* will eat all but the last of them.

   - *`.\{[num]\}keyword`* will match only the *first* occurrence of the pattern which might be found in pattern space.
2. *`.\{[num]\}`* will *require* at least *`[num]`*-count chars to occur *before* keyword to qualify a match, whereas *`.*`* can match *`keyword`* even if it is found at the head of a line.

   - An expression which more closely resembles this behavior in that it will match *up to `[num]`* chars occurring before *`keyword`* is...

     ```sh
     sed "s/.\{0,$n\}keyword/REPLACE/"
     ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what does {$n\} part stand for, I replaced n with dots and stuff but it kept giving error, I'm using GNU sed

Comment: @TolgaVarol - hopefully that clears it up.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit newbie but when I execute "sed 's/.\{0,$n\}://'" this error occurs "sed: -e expression #1, char 14: Invalid content of \{\}" . Excluding {$n\} works though and solved my problem. Any idea with the error?

Comment: @TolgaVarol - it's ok, you just have to set `$n` to some number. If you want to remove 5 chars do `n=5` first.